# How do I dynamically pass a checkbox value from the view to the controller when it is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to send an array of all checked values to the controller every time a checkbox is checked, but cannot figure out how to do this using AJAX.

html.erb:

```
<div class="items">
<input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" value="a">A
<input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" value="b">B
<input type="checkbox" class="item-checkbox" value="c">C
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var selected_items = [];
$(".item-checkbox").click(function() {
        var item = $( this ).val();
        selected_items.push(item);
 }
```

controller:

```
class BudgetController < ApplicationController

  def view

  ....

  end

end
```

How do I pass the selected_items array to the controller without having to reload the page?

Comment: What have you tried? A simple `$.ajax` post call or `$.post` will do this. You just need to serialize the inputs to the `data` property.

Comment: I tried that but how do I access the data in the controller?

Comment: You will need to show your controller code. It would require the same code as handling a normal form.

Comment: Posted my controller code. My checkboxes are not in a form, should they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would involve putting them within a form and getting the form to submit:

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function (event) {       
   event.preventDefault(); // stop form from submitting normally
   var form = $(this); // get the form
   var dataToSend = form.serialize(); // get the submitted form items
   var url = form.attr('action'); // where we're submitting the data to
   $.post(url, dataToSend, function (data) {
      // optional function to deal with returned data
   }).done(function (data) {
      // what to do when it's completed
   }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // what to do if it fails
   });
});
```

You can then handle them like a regular form submission on the server side.