# Multiple form submits from same page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a page which loads a bunch of questions from my database.

The questions all have 2 forms with it.

Like:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <form method="post" action="" id="knowId-XXXXX-y">
        <input type="hidden" name="userKnewStatus" value="YES">
        <input type="hidden" name="knowId" id="knowId" value="#ID">
        <input type="hidden" name="knewStatus" id="knewStatus" value="1">
        <button class="btn btn-success dyk-btn" type="submit">
            Ja <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-fw"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <form method="post" action="" id="knowId-XXXXX-n">
        <input type="hidden" name="userKnewStatus" value="YES">
        <input type="hidden" name="knowId"  id="knowId" value="#ID">
        <input type="hidden" name="knewStatus" id="knewStatus" value="0">
        <button class="btn btn-danger dyk-btn" type="submit">
            Nej <i class="fa fa-meh-o fa-fw"></i>
        </button>
    </form> 
</div>
```

To submit the form i have the following code in Jquery/ajax.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("form").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $( this ), 
            url = $form.attr( 'action' );

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post( url, { knowId: $('#knowId').val(), knewStatus: $('#knewStatus').val() } );

        /* Alerts the results */
        posting.done(function( data ) {
        alert('success');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The forms are getting submitted but due to the duplicate in ID for the form the first values is always sent to the row.

How do i assign the jquery to pick the id from within the form itself?

I'm not fancy in jquery at all but i tried to insert "this" but then i just receive error.

Comment: Why dont you use `<button type='button'>..` and then submit forms on each click?

Comment: I am not so much into jquery / ajax. but i will try to search for something like that. thank you

Comment: `id` attribute **have to** be unique for each element. Otherwise, it doesn't make any sense to use them. Use classes instead and get values like: `$form.find('.class').val()`

Comment: By the way you had an error on  "var $form = $( this ), url = $form.attr( 'action' );". After the first $( this ) you should have a ";" and not a ",".

Comment: @Ted Incorrect. He's declaring two variables. It's like writing `var a=1,b=2`

Comment: Absolutely correct, I didn't see it because of indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ID properties to Classes first of all where you have elements with the same ID, as someone has said already, an ID should be unique on your page. Then you can get that class from the form you've clicked on by doing:

```
$form.find('.knowId').val();
```

Comment: Or even easier: `var posting = $.post( url, $form.serialize() );`

Comment: @ArturFilipiak Correct it would be easier, but technically wouldn't answer the, "Why is my code not working?" question.

Comment: @HereToHelpPHP See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23410289/2117156) I posted on another topic on here, it should help. Don't forget to accept an answer when it answers your question too :).

Comment: @JamieBarker, But it's worth to mention as side-note that jQuery has already dedicated method for this.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak Correct, see the previous comment I aimed to the OP with a link to another answer I gave last year :). They also may not _want_ to send _all_ their form items in the post ;).